# Set title on collpase icon

Tags: javascript, html, primefaces, title

on Primefaces i create a layout with the "collapsible="true"" parameter.
When the pannel is closed, i see only an icon with 4 arrow.
On mouser over the icon, appear the word "Open"
How to change this word?
i make a try with:

```
document.getElementById('west_pnl-toggler').firstChild.title="visualizza";
```

this work fine if i write from console, but doesn't work by running the application, with error:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

how to set this title, or detect if the setting js is ended?

thank's a lot!

Comment: You can use `alerts` or `console.log` for every line and see where your code stops working.

Comment: The node needs to exist **before** the lookup happens, if you have your script above your related _HTML_, make sure to defer it's invocation until the _load_ event

Comment: thank's @PaulS. but how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the following attributes on `p:layout`

```
<p:layout expandTitle="Visualizza" 
          closeTitle="Chiudi"
          collapseTitle="Collapse"
          resizeTitle="Ridimensiona" >
```

Comment: it's work! Grazie mille, ho perso 3 ore per farlo funzionare, ed era semplicissimo.

Comment: Figurati, cmq c'era scritto nella documentazione :)